# Invalid MEX file from any other folder except private folder

Tags: matlab, caffe, mex, matcaffe

I have compiled matcaffe with caffe in Windows.

My current matcaffe folder structure is as below:

```
.
C:\PYTHON\caffe
            |-- matlab
                  |
                  |-- +caffe
                         |
                         |--private
                                |
                                |-- caffe_.mexw64
                                |...
                                |-- all hard linked dlls
```

I have checked `caffe_.mexw64` using dependency walker that the following files are missing:

```
LIBMEX.DLL
LIBMX.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

which is quite obvious from dependency walker. All `caffe-related dll`s are found.

In matlab, I have added the following path:

```
addpath('C:\PYTHON\caffe\matlab');
```

but on running this command:

```
caffe.run_tests()
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\PYTHON\caffe\matlab\+caffe\private\caffe_.mexw64': The
specified procedure could not be found.
Error in caffe.set_mode_cpu (line 5)
caffe_('set_mode_cpu');
Error in caffe.run_tests (line 6)
caffe.set_mode_cpu();
```

Interesting thing is the following. If I go to the `caffe\matlab\+caffe\private` folder and run the same `caffe.run_tests()`, then it runs successfully.

And thereafter only, I can run the `matcaffe` commands without MEX errors from any other folder (as the dlls are then already loaded in the memory).

My questions are:

- What is happening here that I cannot directly run from any other folder?
- How to solve this to get the normal behaviour?

### Update:

Now I see that the same problem has been posted [here](https://blog.csdn.net/zb1165048017/article/details/51702686), but no proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory with the DLLs to the `PATH` environment variable. You can do this from within MATLAB on Windows (this does not work to modify the equivalent `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux and Unix):

```
setenv('PATH',['C:\PYTHON\caffe\matlab\+caffe\private\;',getenv('PATH')]);
```